# How to use where clause on data which is eager loaded in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-query-builder

I want to display only the users who are admin and according to a search term which is entered in the searchbox

I store the keyword first

```
$keyword = $request->get('search');
```

and then

```
$users = User::with('admin')->where('role', 'super_admin')
                    ->where(function ($query) use($keyword){
                        $query->where('id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                        ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
            })->paginate($perPage);
```

This works as im searching terms from main table that is `user` table

But i also want to filter it using admin table columns as

```
$users = User::with('admin')->where('role', 'super_admin')
                    ->where(function ($query) use($keyword){
                        $query->where('id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                        ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                        ->orWhere($this->admin->status, 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
            })->paginate($perPage);
```

This throws an error  `undefined property admin`

Due to this line `->orWhere($this->admin->status, 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");`

So how can i use admin column in filtering data

Answer (score 0):

sample eager loading

```
    $users = User::with([
        'admin' => function($query) use($keyword) {
             $query->where('status', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
        }
    ])
    ->where('role', 'super_admin')
    ->where(function ($query) use($keyword){
                    $query->where('id', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
    })->paginate($perPage);
```